# 'ﬁ' displaying incorrectly in database

Tags: php, mysql, html, entity

I have a mySQL database with the following

> e.g.
> Microeconomics.
>
> The ‘theory of the ï¬rm’
>
> or:
> Resource allocation modiï¬cations.

For some reason, the text that has been input (through CKEditor), has been changed so any instances of `ﬁ` are in the database as 'ï¬'. I believe this is something to do with HTML entities. The text (I believe) was copy-pasted from a word document, which could be part of the problem.

How do I change (in PHP or mySQL) all instances of 'ï¬' into `ﬁ`? When rendered as a PDF by TCPDF, it shows a ? (e.g. financial = ?nancial, significant = signi?cant)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not fix the charset throughout the pipeline?

Comment: Also, `$ charinfo ﬁ`
`U+FB01 LATIN SMALL LIGATURE FI`

Comment: This looks like an interesting option, which I may investigate further at a later date - for now I needed a very quick fix! :)

Comment: Just use utf-8 all the way through is the fix

Comment: Use utf8 encoding everywhere. It will probably fix these issues.
(Hmm, that is exactly what Esailija wrote. So I mean: +1 to that. :-) )

Answer (score -1):

This statement will correct all the false instances for the column that contains the 'ï¬'

```
Update table Set 
  column = replace(column, 'ï¬', 'fi')
```

Comment: Except it won't, because it's actually *three* characters.

Comment: UPDATE `courseconf` SET `courseoutline` = REPLACE(`courseoutline`, 'ï¬', 'fi') seemed to do the trick for 90% of cases

Comment: That is a quickfix, not a solution to the underlying source of the problem. It feels like driving a car without brakes, only to say (after an accident): "They will replace all broken parts at the garage.".

Comment: He only needed a quickfix because there was something copy paste from a word document. When you use CKEditor you can use 'paste from Word button'.

Comment: @user1571215: Unfortunately now other ligatures are broken.